# Finding the sum of the values of a dictionary with matching keys

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, higher-order-functions

I have a nested dictionary of type `[String: [String: Int]]` that looks like this:

```swift
var dict = [
    "A": ["a": 234, "b": 322],
    "B": ["c": 45, "d": 443],
    "C": ["b": 50, "e": 940, "f": 9430, "a": 53029]
]
```

I want to convert it so that the integers of all the same lowercased keys are added together to form another dictionary:

```swift
["a": 53263, "b": 382, "c": 45, "d": 50, "e": 940, "f": 9430]
```

I don't care for the keys `"A", "B", "C"`.

First, I mapped `dict` to extract the nested dictionary:

```swift
let result1 = dict.map { $1 }
// [["b": 322, "a": 234], ["c": 45, "d": 443], ["e": 940, "b": 50, "a": 53029, "f": 9430]]
```

I used the `flatMap` to get the tuple:

```swift
let result2 = dict.map { $1 }.flatMap { $0.map { $0 }}
// [(key: "c", value: 45), (key: "d", value: 443), (key: "f", value: 9430), (key: "e", value: 940), (key: "a", value: 53029), (key: "b", value: 50), (key: "a", value: 234), (key: "b", value: 322)]
```

Finally, I tried to take `result2` and map over each item to add all the values of the same keys and return a dictionary of type `[String: Int]`:

```swift
var tempArray = [String]()
var finalDict = [String: Int]()
var count = 0
let result3 = dict.map { $1 }.flatMap { $0.map { el -> [String: Int] in
    if tempArray.contains(el.key) {
        if let newCount = finalDict[el.key] {
            count += newCount
            finalDict[el.key] = newCount
        }
    } else {
        tempArray.append(el.key)
        finalDict = [el.key: el.value]
    }

    return finalDict
}}
```

But, the result I'm getting is:

```swift
[["b": 322], ["a": 234], ["c": 45], ["d": 443], ["d": 443], ["d": 443], ["f": 9430], ["e": 940]]
```

which shows multiples of the same keys.

Comment: Your `dict` is not of type [String: [String: Int]] as you say, it seems to be [String: [[String: Int]]]. Is this correct?

Comment: You're totally right, but that's actually a typo in recreating my example. Let me try this again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` to create one array of tuples and then `reduce(into:)` to create a dictionary with the keys and the sum of the values per key

```
let result = dict.values
    .flatMap {$0}
    .reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.key, default: 0] += $1.value }
```

Comment: Could you explain `$0[$1.key, default: 0]`?

Comment: Look up the value for the key $1.key and if it doesn't exist insert as value 0 for the key

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. `result2` is an array of tuples, which you could use to construct a dictionary with unique keys by adding their values:

```
var dict = Dictionary(result2, uniquingKeysWith: +)
```

which will give you what you need (order not guaranteed):

```
["c": 45, "a": 53263, "d": 443, "b": 372, "f": 9430, "e": 940]
```

---

There's a slightly simpler way to get your `result2`:

```
let result2 = dict.flatMap { $0.value }.flatMap { $0.map{ $0 } }
```

Comment: I tried `Dictionary(result3, uniquingKeysWith: +)`, but I'm getting the `Circular reference` error. Sorry I had to modify the question a bit so `result3` is now `result2`, but the tuples are essentially the same.

Comment: @Kevvv, hmm.. not sure about circular reference, but if you basically use the version i have: `dict.flatMap { $0.value }.flatMap { $0.map{ $0 } }`, then init the dictionary as above, it works

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `dict` to an array of dictionaries and then use `reduce` to merge the keys.

```
let values = dict.map {$0.value}.flatMap {$0}

let merged = values .flatMap{$0}.reduce([String:Int]()) { (previous, dict) in
    var newDict = previous
    if let lastValue = previous[dict.key] {
        let sum = lastValue + dict.value
        newDict[dict.key] = sum
    } else {
        newDict.updateValue(dict.value, forKey: dict.key)
    }
    return newDict
}

print(merged)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary `uniquingKeysWith` initializer and use the plus method to sum them up:

---

```
let result: Dictionary = .init(dict.flatMap(\.value), uniquingKeysWith: +)
```